# Perl how can I get values from a hash with key from another hash

Tags: perl

I have two hash, first one %hash contain uniq key and values.

The other one %channel contain only the Stores which are already present as values from %hash

I would like to display all the Category id *(for example Category::1375567 etc..)* which refer to the Store *(for example Store::CAR)*

Here below the expected result of what I need, it will be more efficient than my explication.

```
my %hash = (
        'Category::1375567' => 'Store::CAR|Category::1375567|CAR Concert',
        'Category::1299556' => 'Store::CHANNEL|Category::1299556|Culture',
        'Category::1314571' => 'Store::TV|Category::1314571|Emissions',
        'Category::1375568' => 'Store::CAR|Category::1375568|Sciences',
        'Category::1314570' => 'Store::TV|Category::1314570|Info',
        'Category::1314572' => 'Store::TV|Category::1314572|Jeunesse',
        'Category::1314569' => 'Store::TV|Category::1314569|Séries & Fictions',
        'Category::1294556' => 'Store::CHANNEL|Category::1294556|Documentaire',
        'Category::1326557' => 'Store::CHANNEL|Category::1326557|Sport'
);

my %channel = (
        'Store::TV' => 'Store::TV',
        'Store::CAR' => 'Store::CAR',
        'Store::CHANNEL' => 'Store::CHANNEL'
);
```

**Expected result**

```
    Store::CAR
Store::CAR|Category::1375567|CAR Concert
Store::CAR|Category::1375568|Sciences

    Store::CHANNEL
Store::CHANNEL|Category::1294556|Documentaire
Store::CHANNEL|Category::1299556|Culture
Store::CHANNEL|Category::1326557|Sport

    Store::TV
Store::TV|Category::1314569|Séries & Fictions
Store::TV|Category::1314570|Info
Store::TV|Category::1314571|Emissions
Store::TV|Category::1314572|Jeunesse
```

**Actual result**

```
    Store::CAR
Store::CAR|Category::1375567|CAR Concert
Store::CAR|Category::1375568|Sciences
Store::CHANNEL|Category::1294556|Documentaire
Store::CHANNEL|Category::1299556|Culture
Store::CHANNEL|Category::1326557|Sport
Store::TV|Category::1314569|Séries & Fictions
Store::TV|Category::1314570|Info
Store::TV|Category::1314571|Emissions
Store::TV|Category::1314572|Jeunesse

    Store::CHANNEL
Store::CAR|Category::1375567|CAR Concert
Store::CAR|Category::1375568|Sciences
Store::CHANNEL|Category::1294556|Documentaire
Store::CHANNEL|Category::1299556|Culture
Store::CHANNEL|Category::1326557|Sport
Store::TV|Category::1314569|Séries & Fictions
Store::TV|Category::1314570|Info
Store::TV|Category::1314571|Emissions
Store::TV|Category::1314572|Jeunesse
```

Here what I've done so far

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';

my %hash = (
        'Category::1375567' => 'Store::CAR|Category::1375567|CAR Concert',
        'Category::1299556' => 'Store::CHANNEL|Category::1299556|Culture',
        'Category::1314571' => 'Store::TV|Category::1314571|Emissions',
        'Category::1375568' => 'Store::CAR|Category::1375568|Sciences',
        'Category::1314570' => 'Store::TV|Category::1314570|Info',
        'Category::1314572' => 'Store::TV|Category::1314572|Jeunesse',
        'Category::1314569' => 'Store::TV|Category::1314569|Séries & Fictions',
        'Category::1294556' => 'Store::CHANNEL|Category::1294556|Documentaire',
        'Category::1326557' => 'Store::CHANNEL|Category::1326557|Sport'
);


my %channel = (
        'Store::TV' => 'Store::TV',
        'Store::CAR' => 'Store::CAR',
        'Store::CHANNEL' => 'Store::CHANNEL'
);

if (%channel) {
        foreach (sort keys %channel) {
                say "\t", $_;
                my @tab = grep{/'$_'/} sort values %hash;
                if (@tab) {
                        foreach my $line (@tab) {
                                say $line;
                        }
                        say "";
                }
        }
}

#say Dumper(\%hash, \%channel);

__END__
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove some redundancy to make the hashes smaller.

Also, add [utf8](https://perldoc.pl/utf8) as the script contains the character `é`; to get it printed correctly, add [open](https://perldoc.pl/open).

Transform the first hash so that you key the values by the common value. As there are multiple values per this transformed key, use a hash of arrays.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use utf8;
use open OUT => ':encoding(UTF-8)', ':std';

my %hash = (
        '1375567' => 'Store::CAR|CAR Concert',
        '1299556' => 'Store::CHANNEL|Culture',
        '1314571' => 'Store::TV|Emissions',
        '1375568' => 'Store::CAR|Sciences',
        '1314570' => 'Store::TV|Info',
        '1314572' => 'Store::TV|Jeunesse',
        '1314569' => 'Store::TV|Séries & Fictions',
        '1294556' => 'Store::CHANNEL|Documentaire',
        '1326557' => 'Store::CHANNEL|Sport'
);

my %channel;
@channel{qw{ Store::TV Store::CAR Store::CHANNEL }} = ();

my %transformed;
for my $category (keys %hash) {
    my ($val1, $val2) = split /\|/, $hash{$category};
    push @{ $transformed{$val1} }, [$category, $val2];
}

for my $ch (sort keys %channel) {
    say ' ' x 4, $ch;
    local $" = '|';
    say "Category::@$_" for sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @{ $transformed{$ch} };
    say "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following demo code creates new hash reference with `$stores` where key is `store id` and values copied from `%hash`.

Using keys from hash `%channel` output data from hash reference with `$stores`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use utf8;

my $stores;
my %hash = (
        'Category::1375567' => 'Store::CAR|Category::1375567|CAR Concert',
        'Category::1299556' => 'Store::CHANNEL|Category::1299556|Culture',
        'Category::1314571' => 'Store::TV|Category::1314571|Emissions',
        'Category::1375568' => 'Store::CAR|Category::1375568|Sciences',
        'Category::1314570' => 'Store::TV|Category::1314570|Info',
        'Category::1314572' => 'Store::TV|Category::1314572|Jeunesse',
        'Category::1314569' => 'Store::TV|Category::1314569|Séries & Fictions',
        'Category::1294556' => 'Store::CHANNEL|Category::1294556|Documentaire',
        'Category::1326557' => 'Store::CHANNEL|Category::1326557|Sport'
);

my %channel = (
        'Store::TV' => 'Store::TV',
        'Store::CAR' => 'Store::CAR',
        'Store::CHANNEL' => 'Store::CHANNEL'
);

for ( values %hash ) {
        my($id,$cat,$desc) = split /\|/;
        push @{$stores->{$id}}, $_;
}

for my $id ( sort keys %channel ) {
        say ' ' x 4 . $id;
        say $_ for @{$stores->{$id}};
        say '';
}

exit 0;
```

Output

```
    Store::CAR
Store::CAR|Category::1375567|CAR Concert
Store::CAR|Category::1375568|Sciences

    Store::CHANNEL
Store::CHANNEL|Category::1294556|Documentaire
Store::CHANNEL|Category::1299556|Culture
Store::CHANNEL|Category::1326557|Sport

    Store::TV
Store::TV|Category::1314569|Séries & Fictions
Store::TV|Category::1314570|Info
Store::TV|Category::1314571|Emissions
Store::TV|Category::1314572|Jeunesse
```